# Dumping a table's content in sqlite3 to be imported into a new database

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there an easy way of dumping a SQLite database table into a text string with `insert` statements to be imported into the same table of a different database?

In my specific example, I have a table called **log_entries** with various columns. At the end of every day, I'd like to create a string which can then be dumped into an other database with a table of the same structure called **archive**. (And empty the table **log_entries**)

I know about the `attach` command to create new databases. I actually wish to add it to an existing one rather than creating a new one every day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ATTACH "%backup_file%" AS Backup;
INSERT INTO Backup.Archive SELECT * FROM log_entries;
DELETE FROM log_entries;
DETACH Backup;
```

All you need to do is replace %backup_file% with the path to your backup database. This approach considers that your Archive table is already defined and that you are using the same database file to cumulate your archive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sqlite3 exclusion.sqlite '.dump exclusion' 
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE exclusion (word string);
INSERT INTO "exclusion" VALUES('books');
INSERT INTO "exclusion" VALUES('rendezvousing');
INSERT INTO "exclusion" VALUES('motherlands');
INSERT INTO "exclusion" VALUES('excerpt');
...
```